# Wpf Combobox SelectionChanged event CommandParameter confuse

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, selectedindex

I have some academic question here. Look at markup:

```
<Grid  Margin="10,10,10,10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
                Margin="5"
                Width="100">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, 
                                        Path=SelectedIndex}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" 
            Content="Set SelectedIndex to 0" 
            Width="100" 
            Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"
            Margin="5">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

This is `DataContext` class.

```
class Class1Context : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _selectedIndex;
    public Int32 SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            _selectedIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<Object> _testCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Object> TestCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _testCommand ?? (_testCommand =
                new RelayCommand<Object>(TestMethod));
        }
    }

    private void TestMethod(Object obj)
    {
        var index = (Int32) obj;
        var selIndex = SelectedIndex;
    }


    private RelayCommand _buttonCommand;
    public RelayCommand ButtonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _buttonCommand ?? (_buttonCommand =
                new RelayCommand(ButtonCommandMethod));
        }
    }

    private void ButtonCommandMethod()
    {
        SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

So, where is the problem? Here it is. When I select `Item2` or `Item3`, then `SelectedIndex` property equals 1 or 2. For example, I clicked `Item2` and `SelectedIndex` equals 1 now. Hence, when I click the `Button` and set `SelectedIndex` to 0 it generates the event `SelectionChanged` in `Combobox`. It is logically. Then, event fires the bounded command `TestCommand`.
And in `TestMethod` index (`CommandParameter`) equals to 1 (**one!**) and it is a problem, in spite of `SelectedIndex` of `DataContext` equals to 0 (zero). 
So, is it a `Wpf` bug or something else?

Comment: why are you trying to handle the behaviour of the ComboBox twice, IMO in the scenario above you only require to bind the SelectedIndex property. An any behaviour you want to execute you should put this as part of the setter implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"


<ComboBox>
                        <ComboBox.Items>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="item1" >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Selected">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding item1Cmd}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="item2" >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Selected">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding item2Cmd}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem Content="item3" >
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Selected">
                                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding item3Cmd}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox.Items>
                    </ComboBox>
```

This way worked fine for me. I'm aware of a little code overhead using the same code for each ComboBoxItems.

If your ComboBox is needs a dynamic load then you should be able to add the Interaction.Triggers in code behind

Answer (score -2):

```
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestCommand}" ></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```